# Configuration Language (Locale ID) in version info

Tags: delphi-xe3

In Delphi XE3, the configuration is not holding the language option chosen in project > options > Version Info.
I tried to save the .optset file, but it did not work.

Comment: The IDE is useless at this sort of thing. Don't rely on it for building your program. You need an automated build process which generates the version resource.

Comment: I understand. Thanks!